# C++ skips function

Tags: c++, function

I am making a hangman program to practice my functions.
This is my startup to test a function.
For some reason he skips the function      char guessing(char guess);
The only thing he puts on the screen is the "Welcome to Hangman 2.0" sentence and the "This is what you entered" sentence.
If you know what's wrong could you please tell me also why it's wrong.
Beceause I'am 15 and I like to learn things.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


char guess;

char guessing(char guess);
void check();

int main()
{
    cout <<"Welcome to Hangman 2.0. Enjoy, have fun and good luck!!\n\n";

    check();

    return 0;
}



char guessing(char guess)
{
    cout <<"Enter a guess: ";
    cin >> guess;

    return guess;
}

void check()
{
    char guessing(char guess);
    cout <<"This is what you entered: ";
    cout << guess;
}
```

Comment: You need to get a book on C++ and learn how to call a function from code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I have one but like I said I'am 15 and the book is in Enlgish wich is not my mother language so it's hard for me to understand some things.

Comment: Yes, I'm surprised that this compiles. What is the compiler thinking here?

Comment: @Stijn Oh... does this help? http://members.chello.nl/~s.pampiermole/C++/lswmc/lswmc.html

Comment: @MrLister : first line of `check()` declares an `extern` function named guessing. The 3rd line refers to a global variable (see decls near top of file) named `guess`.

Comment: @MrLister Thank you so much for this, I think this will help me with allot of things in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling your function correctly, try with:

```
void check()
{
    char ch = guessing();
    cout <<"This is what you entered: ";
    cout << ch;
}
```

and modify your guessing function like that:

```
char guessing()
{
    char guess;
    cout <<"Enter a guess: ";
    cin >> guess;

    return guess;
}
```

This way you don't need a `guess` member variable and you don't need to pass argument to your function.

Aside from that, calling a function say `char guessing(char guess);` in C++ would be something like:

```
char res = guessing('a');
```

you don't specifies return types or parameters types when calling a function.

Comment: Thanks it works perfect! could you just give me some more information about the char res = guessing('a'); thing, i don't understand it exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Your `check()` function is incorrect, you're defining a function here not calling one.  You want:

```
void check()
{
    char c = guessing();
    cout << "This is what you entered: " << c;
}
```

And then `guessing()` shouldn't accept a parameter, it should just return a char.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call

```
 guessing(guess);
```

not

```
char guessing(char guess);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this, replace your check function by this :::

```
void check()
{
    char guess;
    guess = guessing(guess);
    cout <<"This is what you entered: ";
    cout << guess;
}
```

But the parameter of your function guessing is useless...